# Android version 4.0.4: Incorrect result code returned for activity for setting a password

Tags: android, android-activity, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I launch the set password activity by using the intent `DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD`. When the user sets a password I want to be notified (basically then my app knows that the master passcode is set for the device). However, in my `onActivityResult` function I get a `RESULT_CANCELLED` action when the user tries to set a new PIN or alphanumeric password. I have only observed this with Android version 4.0.4. Does anyone know how I can find if the user has set a PIN or a alphanumeric password on ICS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found this solution. Make a class to extend the `android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver` to listen for any change associated with the device master password. Override the `public void onPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent)` method to receive a call back when there is a change in the passcode. The following code for `onPasswordChanged` worked for me.

```
public class MyDeviceAdminReceiver extends android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver {


@Override
public void onPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPasswordChanged(context, intent);

    Log.d(TAG, "onPasswordChanged:");
    boolean masterPasswordEnabled = false;
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, MyDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
    DevicePolicyManager devPolicyMan = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

    // Update configuration based on actual password state on the device
    if (devPolicyMan.isAdminActive(component)) {
          Log.d("master_password_debug", "admin is active");
          devPolicyMan.setPasswordMinimumLength(component, 1);
          masterPasswordEnabled = devPolicyMan.isActivePasswordSufficient();
        }

}

}
```

Use masterPasswordEnabled even if the resultCode is `RESULT_CANCELLED`.